# Ruby/Juggernaut error - Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cappuccino, juggernaut

I'm playing around with https://github.com/elii/Cappuccino-X-Juggernaut, which is basically a juggernaut chat for rails, and I get the following errors when I try to submit a post. Could someone tell me where this error is coming from?

**Please tell me which files I should post so that someone can diagnose this error.**

```
Processing JuggernautController#send_message (for ::1 at 2011-07-30 16:19:47) [GET]
  Parameters: {"sender"=>"w", "message"=>"hello"}

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  app/controllers/juggernaut_controller.rb:10:in `send_message'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'

Rendered rescues/_trace (52.2ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (0.4ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your juggernaut server isn't running? I would install (if not already) and run it as a daemon or separate screen.

More info on [juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut)

Comment: I did `juggernaut -c juggernaut.yml` and terminal output `info  - socket.io started`? Do I need to do something more to start the server?

Comment: Looks like it's running. Restart your Rails app and see if it works.

Comment: No, I checked that I have the server running and restarted the app but I still get the error. Do you know what else could be causing this problem?